# Removing the wordpress header

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I've been searching in this topic for almost 2 hours and I couldn't find an answer, My website is hosted on WordPress and I would like to remove this part that I covered with the red color:

[image]

On specific pages that I choose, so It'll end up like that:

[image: https://preview.ibb.co/dUyYb8/2.png]

[Website](http://www.graspdating.com)

It seems like no one has figured this out yet

Comment: Just on specific pages

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code, you can either go play in the HTML or the CSS.
**1) HTML**
Find the file that contains the `<div class="header-wrapper">`, which is probably in header.php or index.php. 
Around it, add: 
`<?php if (!is_page(the-id-of-the-page-you-dont-want-it-to-appear)) {?>`  (the div...) ... `<?php } ?>`. 
That way, you won't add that part of the code on that page only. In your case, it's ID=2. 
You need to add the same thing around the `<div class="hero-container">` element. 

**2) CSS**
Even easier, you just need to add:

```
.page-id-2 .header-wrapper, 
.page-id-2 .hero-container {
   display: none;
}
```

And you can add that for all the pages you don't want it to appear. To find the page ID, go in the WP-admin and go edit the page. You'll see the ID in the URL of your browser.

Comment: Why did it leave the footer like that tho https://pasteboard.co/HwS7u4q.png

Comment: Because your page is not long enough. You need more content, or to fix your footer below (but that can cause a lot of issues). The footer is directly following the content. That's why.

Comment: Again, most youtube videos out there are completely useless, I was looking about how to change the background color, and the main content in specific pages that I choose,
I tried adding that code 
.page-id-2
{
background: #FFFFFF
}

.page-id-2 .content {
background: #FFFFFF
}
to Custom CSS but nothing has changed